# Fixer.io Currency Converter Not Working

Tags: magento2.4, currency, convert

Magento offers an out-of-the-box integration to the third party currency conversion api Fixer.io. Having acquired a free api key I have attempted to update the currency rates on my magento build to be given the error message "No API Key was specified or an invalid API Key was specified." I've generated a number of api keys and got the same message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The api for Fixer.io has changed from what Magento has integrated. First of all the url has changed, and secondly the api key must be sent in as a custom header with the key "apikey", not as part of the url. To make these changes in Magento requires a custom module to override the Magento Fixer class.

First of all, the standard files for creating and registering a module:

<Vendor>\<Module>\registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
   'Vendor_Module',
   __DIR__
);
```

<Vendor>\<Module>\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.1"></module>
</config>
```

Next, we tell Magento to load out FixerIo instead of their own FixerIo:

<Vendor>\<Module>\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    
    <preference for="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\Import\FixerIo" 
                type="Vendor\Module\Model\Currency\Import\FixerIo"
    />
    
</config>
```

And finally, we copy/paste the existing Magento code and make our changes. We have to copy/paste the entire file because Magento have used `private` scope on a lot of functions / properties instead of `protected` and we require access to them, so...

The key differences here are line 11 (`const CURRENCY_CONVERTER_URL` is new api endpoint) and lines 129-132, where we set the headers with our api key.

<Vendor>\<Module>\Model\Currency\Import\FixerIo.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Currency\Import;

use \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class FixerIo extends \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\Import\FixerIo
{
    private $scopeConfig;

    const CURRENCY_CONVERTER_URL = 'https://api.apilayer.com/fixer/latest?symbols{{CURRENCY_TO}}&base={{CURRENCY_FROM}}'; // changed constant
    
    const API_KEY_CONFIG_PATH = 'currency/fixerio/api_key';
    
    /**
     * Initialize dependencies
     *
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $httpClientFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $httpClientFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($currencyFactory, $scopeConfig, $httpClientFactory);
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function fetchRates()
    {
        $data = [];
        $currencies = $this->_getCurrencyCodes();
        $defaultCurrencies = $this->_getDefaultCurrencyCodes();

        foreach ($defaultCurrencies as $currencyFrom) {
            if (!isset($data[$currencyFrom])) {
                $data[$currencyFrom] = [];
            }
            $data = $this->convertBatch($data, $currencyFrom, $currencies);
            ksort($data[$currencyFrom]);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Return currencies convert rates in batch mode
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @param string $currencyFrom
     * @param array $currenciesTo
     * @return array
     */
    private function convertBatch(array $data, string $currencyFrom, array $currenciesTo): array
    {
        $accessKey = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::API_KEY_CONFIG_PATH, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        
        if (empty($accessKey)) {
            $this->_messages[] = __('No API Key was specified or an invalid API Key was specified.');
            $data[$currencyFrom] = $this->makeEmptyResponse($currenciesTo);
            return $data;
        }

        $currenciesStr = implode(',', $currenciesTo);
        $url = str_replace(
            ['{{ACCESS_KEY}}', '{{CURRENCY_FROM}}', '{{CURRENCY_TO}}'],
            [$accessKey, $currencyFrom, $currenciesStr],
            self::CURRENCY_CONVERTER_URL
        );
        // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
        set_time_limit(0);
        try {
            $response = $this->getServiceResponse($url);
        } finally {
            ini_restore('max_execution_time');
        }

        if (!$this->validateResponse($response, $currencyFrom)) {
            $data[$currencyFrom] = $this->makeEmptyResponse($currenciesTo);
            return $data;
        }

        foreach ($currenciesTo as $currencyTo) {
            if ($currencyFrom == $currencyTo) {
                $data[$currencyFrom][$currencyTo] = $this->_numberFormat(1);
            } else {
                if (empty($response['rates'][$currencyTo])) {
                    $serviceHost =  $this->getServiceHost($url);
                    $this->_messages[] = __('We can\'t retrieve a rate from %1 for %2.', $serviceHost, $currencyTo);
                    $data[$currencyFrom][$currencyTo] = null;
                } else {
                    $data[$currencyFrom][$currencyTo] = $this->_numberFormat(
                        (double)$response['rates'][$currencyTo]
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $url
     * @param int $retry
     * @return array|mixed
     * @override
     * @see \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\Import\FixerIo::convertBatch()
     */
    private function getServiceResponse($url, $retry = 0)
    {
        $accessKey = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::API_KEY_CONFIG_PATH, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        
        
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClient $httpClient */
        $httpClient = $this->httpClientFactory->create();
        $response = [];
        
        try {
            
            $jsonResponse = $httpClient->setUri($url)
                ->setConfig(
                    [
                        'timeout' => $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                            'currency/fixerio/timeout',
                            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                        ),
                    ]
                )
                ->setHeaders([
                    'Content-Type' => 'text/plain',
                    'apikey' => $accessKey,
                ])
                ->request('GET')
                ->getBody();

            $response = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
            
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            if ($retry == 0) {
                $response = $this->getServiceResponse($url, 1);
            }
        }
        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Validates rates response.
     *
     * @param array $response
     * @param string $baseCurrency
     * @return bool
     */
    private function validateResponse(array $response, string $baseCurrency): bool
    {
        if ($response['success']) {
            return true;
        }

        $errorCodes = [
            101 => __('No API Key was specified or an invalid API Key was specified.'),
            102 => __('The account this API request is coming from is inactive.'),
            105 => __('The "%1" is not allowed as base currency for your subscription plan.', $baseCurrency),
            201 => __('An invalid base currency has been entered.'),
        ];

        $this->_messages[] = $errorCodes[$response['error']['code']] ?? __('Currency rates can\'t be retrieved.');

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Creates array for provided currencies with empty rates.
     *
     * @param array $currenciesTo
     * @return array
     */
    private function makeEmptyResponse(array $currenciesTo): array
    {
        return array_fill_keys($currenciesTo, null);
    }

    /**
     * Get currency converter service host.
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @return string
     */
    private function getServiceHost(string $url): string
    {
        if (!$this->currencyConverterServiceHost) {
            // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
            $this->currencyConverterServiceHost = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) . '://'
                // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
                . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
        }
        return $this->currencyConverterServiceHost;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just for improve your answer, add `<sequence><module name="Magento_Directory"/></sequence>` inside your module tag since it depends on it.